# Chaplin.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, chaplinjs

Sometimes I get an error like this [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bou7z.png).
Why do they occur?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you're trying to access a property of an undefined value. For example:

```
var test; // test is now undefined, typeof(test) would return "undefined"
test.myPropertyName // => throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined'
```

So, sounds like you're trying to perform an operation using an uninitalized variable.

Comment: I am getting this error in my application and in ost.io when move from CollectionView. It seems this is a problem of Chaplin.js.